# Airflow - How to encrypt connection that is built through Extra

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, airflow-connections

I've a connection to AWS S3 on Airflow that is made with Extra config:

- aws_access_key_id
- aws_secret_access_key
  However, since this credentials are stored on Extra field, it's not encrypted and everyone that has access to Airflow UI can see those value:
  [image]

Is there any way to encrypt those connection/values on Extra fields?

Thanks?